# AnimationDrawable stretches

Tags: android, android-animation

I implemented an ImageView with an `AnimationDrawable` however it's stretching to fill the entire ImageView.

My Image View is:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/catImageView"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And my animation code is:

```
ImageView catImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.catImageView);
catImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat_awake_animation);
catImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
catAwakeAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)catImageView.getBackground();
catAwakeAnimation.setOneShot(false);
```

Apparently setting the `setScaleType()` does not work!

How do I make it fit accordingly without stretching and distortion?

Answer (score 0):

By the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), `FIT_CENTER` will scale the image, but `CENTER` will not.

> `ImageView.ScaleType CENTER`
>
> Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.

And

> `ImageView.ScaleType FIT_CENTER`
>
> Scale the image using CENTER.